# Map from quotient group

Tags: group-theory

I well known that given a group G and a normal subgroup H we can find an epimorphism from G to G/H. I am trying to find conditions both in G and H to find a map in the other directions, it seems possible to fix once and for all on representative for every class in G/H and send each element on himself on the group G, but  this does not seem to be formal to me, there is another way to do this?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "map in the other direction"? There's always the inclusion map, and if $G$ is finite and $H \ne G$ then there is no epimorphism.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but if $f:G \to G'$ is a morphism and $H \subseteq \text{Ker}(f)$, then there is a unique morphism $\bar f : G/H \to G'$ such that $\bar f \circ π = f$, where $π : G \to G/H$ is the canonical epimorphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course there is always a trivial group homomorphism $G/H \to G$. I think you are asking whether you can find a map that is compatible with the epimorphism $G \to G/H$, i.e., such that the composition $G/H \to G \to G/H$ is the identity. You can always find such a set-theoretic map $G/H \to G$ by choosing an element in each coset (using the axiom of choice if necessary). What if we want this map to be a homomorphism? Then this map is called a [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)). Such a section exists if and only if $G$ is isomorphic to a [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) of $H$ and $G/H$.

Comment: Would you be so kind to add a reference to the definition of section (as in wikipedia or else)? Thank you. I haven't  found anything.

Comment: @PeptideChain Sure, I added a link to the [Wikipedia page on sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)). You can also find a more in-depth discussion in [these notes of mine on semidirect products](http://aprovost.profweb.ca/math/semidirectnotes/semidirectnotes.pdf). Hope it helps!